# What do I need to do to get qrandom to pipe data correctly into a running script without it throwing errors?

Tags: bash, shell

Recently, I have failed to input data from qrandom with a script. The pipe script is down below.

```
while true do
    echo 1
    echo $((qrandom --int --max 69 --min 1))
    echo 2
    echo $((qrandom --int --max 69 --min 1))
    done | ./RNGAI
```

The error has been thrown from the terminal. It is a never-ending error of "-nan." I downloaded a free opensource script that handles weights for predictions. There is nothing wrong with the script as I tested it manually, but everytime I try to pipe data into it. It rejects it!

What am I doing wrong that prevents the script that I downloaded to throw these errors?

```
 Enter lottery number 1. 
 Enter Lottery number 2. 
-nan
-nan
 Enter lottery number 1. 
 Enter Lottery number 2. 
-nan
-nan
 Enter lottery number 1. 
 Enter Lottery number 2. 
-nan
-nan
 Enter lottery number 1. 
 Enter Lottery number 2.
```

Comment: Did you perhaps intend command substitution `$( ... )` rather than arithmetic evaluation `$(( ... ))` ? In any case, is there any good reason to do `echo $(some command)` rather than simply `some command`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are piping in only the last `echo`. Try a "compound command" like

```
{ echo 1
  ...
  echo ...; } | ...
```

or a single `echo` or `printf` for all the input lines like

```
$ echo 1$'\n'"$(qrandom...)"$'\n'2...
```

And, too many parentheses in the "command substitutions"...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Maybe scratch offs >:)